# How do I send a database to someone else?

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2014, ssms

I am working with a more experienced database admin and he wants me to send him a database that I created.  However, I cannot figure out where the database is stored on disk.  I am using Microsoft SSMS.

Answer (score 5):

```
Select a.name, b.physical_name 
from sys.databases a 
join sys.master_files b 
    on a.Database_id = b.database_id 
Where a.name = 'NAME_OF_YOUR_DATABASE'
```

This will show you the location on disk.. (can't move it though).

Backup the database:

```
BACKUP Database NAME_OF_YOUR_DATABASE
To Disk = N'C:\Databases\NAME_OF_YOUR_DATABASE.bak With Compression
```